# How to stop a while loop that is a part of a socket thread using tkinter?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

The codes that are written below connect a user to another user. The problem is about when the client user quits the application, an empty string with date information is still printing on the screen of the server user because of the while loop that starts on the 57'th line. So my questions is, how can i stop receiving empty string messages after the client user close the application?
Thank you.

**server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
from datetime import datetime
import socket
import threading
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Server")

text = tk.Text(master=root)
text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

entry = tk.Entry(master=root)
entry.pack(expand=True, fill="x")

frame = tk.Frame(master=root)
frame.pack()


def buttons():
    for i in "Connect", "Send", "Clear", "Exit":
        b = tk.Button(master=frame, text=i)
        b.pack(side="left")
        yield b


b1, b2, b3, b4 = buttons()


class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.__c = None

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.__c

    @c.setter
    def c(self, c):
        self.__c = c

    @c.deleter
    def c(self):
        del self.__c

    def connect(self):
        self.s.bind(("", 12345))
        self.s.listen(10)
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        text.insert("insert", "Date: {}\nConnected.\n".format(now))
        c, addr = self.s.accept()
        text.insert("insert", "Date: {}\n{} connected.\n".format(str(datetime.now())[:-7], addr))
        self.__c = c
        while True:
            data = str(self.__c.recv(1024))[1:]
            now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
            text.insert("insert", "\nDate: {}\nClient: {}\n".format(now, data))
            time.sleep(2)

    def send(self):
        respond = str(entry.get())
        self.__c.sendall(bytes(respond.encode("utf-8")))
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        entry.delete("0", "end")
        text.insert("insert", "\nDate: {}\nServer: {}\n".format(now, respond))


s1 = Server()


def connect():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=s1.connect)
    t1.start()


def send():
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=s1.send)
    t2.start()


def destroy():
    root.destroy()


def clear():
    text.delete("1.0", "end")


b1.configure(command=connect)
b2.configure(command=send)
b3.configure(command=clear)
b4.configure(command=destroy)

t0 = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop)
t0.run()
```

**client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
from datetime import datetime
import socket
import threading
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Client")

text = tk.Text(master=root)
text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

entry = tk.Entry(master=root)
entry.pack(expand=True, fill="x")

frame = tk.Frame(master=root)
frame.pack()


def buttons():
    for i in "Connect", "Send", "Clear", "Exit":
        b = tk.Button(master=frame, text=i)
        b.pack(side="left")
        yield b


b1, b2, b3, b4 = buttons()


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    @property
    def s(self):
        return self.__s

    @s.deleter
    def s(self):
        del self.__s

    @s.setter
    def s(self, s):
        self.__s = s

    def connect(self):
        self.__s.connect(("", 12345))
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        text.insert("insert", "Tarih: {}\nSunucuya bağlandı.\n".format(now))
        while True:
            data = str(self.__s.recv(1024))[1:]
            now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
            text.insert("insert", "\nTarih: {}\nİstemci: {}\n".format(now, data))
            time.sleep(2)

    def send(self):
        respond = str(entry.get())
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        self.__s.sendall(bytes(respond.encode("utf-8")))
        entry.delete("0", "end")
        text.insert("insert", "\nTarih: {}\nİstemci: {}\n".format(now, respond))


c1 = Client()


def connect():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=c1.connect)
    t1.start()


def send():
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=c1.send)
    t2.start()


def destroy():
    root.destroy()


def clear():
    text.delete("1.0", "end")


b1.configure(command=connect)
b2.configure(command=send)
b3.configure(command=clear)
b4.configure(command=destroy)

t0 = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop)
t0.run()
```

Comment: I assume that it should be `try: import Tkinter as tk`? otherwise this fails in python 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the below codes.

**server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
from datetime import datetime
import socket
import threading
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Server")

text = tk.Text(master=root)
text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

entry = tk.Entry(master=root)
entry.pack(expand=True, fill="x")

frame = tk.Frame(master=root)
frame.pack()


def buttons():
    for i in "Connect", "Send", "Clear", "Disconnect", "Exit":
        b = tk.Button(master=frame, text=i)
        b.pack(side="left")
        yield b


b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 = buttons()


class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.__c = None

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.__c

    @c.setter
    def c(self, c):
        self.__c = c

    @c.deleter
    def c(self):
        del self.__c

    def connect(self):
        self.s.bind(("", 12345))
        self.s.listen(10)
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        text.insert("insert", "Date: {}\nConnected.\n".format(now))
        c, addr = self.s.accept()
        text.insert("insert", "Date: {}\n{} connected.\n".format(str(datetime.now())[:-7], addr))
        self.__c = c
        self.condition()

    def condition(self):
        while self.__c is not None:
            data = str(self.__c.recv(1024))[1:]
            now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
            text.insert("insert", "\nDate: {}\nClient: {}\n".format(now, data))
            time.sleep(2)

    def send(self):
        respond = str(entry.get())
        self.__c.sendall(bytes(respond.encode("utf-8")))
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        entry.delete("0", "end")
        text.insert("insert", "\nDate: {}\nServer: {}\n".format(now, respond))


s1 = Server()


def connect():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=s1.connect)
    t1.start()


def send():
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=s1.send)
    t2.start()


def disconnect():
    s1.c = None


def destroy():
    root.destroy()


def clear():
    text.delete("1.0", "end")


b1.configure(command=connect)
b2.configure(command=send)
b3.configure(command=clear)
b4.configure(command=disconnect)
b5.configure(command=destroy)

t0 = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop)
t0.run()
```

**client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
from datetime import datetime
import socket
import threading
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Client")

text = tk.Text(master=root)
text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

entry = tk.Entry(master=root)
entry.pack(expand=True, fill="x")

frame = tk.Frame(master=root)
frame.pack()


def buttons():
    for i in "Connect", "Send", "Clear", "Disconnect", "Exit":
        b = tk.Button(master=frame, text=i)
        b.pack(side="left")
        yield b


b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 = buttons()


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    @property
    def s(self):
        return self.__s

    @s.deleter
    def s(self):
        del self.__s

    @s.setter
    def s(self, s):
        self.__s = s

    def connect(self):
        self.__s.connect(("", 12345))
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        text.insert("insert", "Date: {}\nConnected.\n".format(now))
        self.condition()

    def condition(self):
        while self.__s is not None:
            data = str(self.__s.recv(1024))[1:]
            now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
            text.insert("insert", "\nDate: {}\Server: {}\n".format(now, data))
            time.sleep(2)

    def send(self):
        respond = str(entry.get())
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        self.__s.sendall(bytes(respond.encode("utf-8")))
        entry.delete("0", "end")
        text.insert("insert", "\nDate: {}\nClient: {}\n".format(now, respond))


c1 = Client()


def connect():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=c1.connect)
    t1.start()


def send():
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=c1.send)
    t2.start()


def clear():
    text.delete("1.0", "end")


def destroy():
    root.destroy()


def disconnect():
    c1.s = None


b1.configure(command=connect)
b2.configure(command=send)
b3.configure(command=clear)
b4.configure(command=disconnect)
b5.configure(command=destroy)
t0 = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop)
t0.run()
```